# Программа состоящая из двух потоков разваливается из за использования QTimer-a

Tags: qt, многопоточность

**Сделал программу двух поточную и добавил туда таймеры от QTimer-a, программа стала разваливаться.**

Когда я в одно поточной программе использую таймеры от QTimer-a то она прекрасно работает.

Когда в двух поточной программе закоментирую таймеры то программа прекрасно работает.

---

mainwindows.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

     QTimer * pB_timers[4];

private slots:
    // -- слоты таймеров
    void DD1_timer_0();
    void DD2_timer_1();
    void DD3_timer_2();
    void DD4_timer_3();
    void DD5_timer_4();
    ...




 class MyThread_priem: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    void Clear_Struct();
//    void Receiving_a_Message();
    //--    переменные
    unsigned char  can_usb;
    unsigned short speed_bit;              
    unsigned char  can_device;
     //--    вектора
    TPCANMsg_priem trcanmsg_priem;
    TPCANTimestamp  TPCANTime;

private:

signals:
    void update();  
    void update_m(ulong, unsigned char, unsigned char, QString, ulong, unsigned short, unsigned short);

public slots:
    void Receiving_a_Message();  
    static void ProcessMessage(TPCANMsg_priem msg);  
    void Start_tehn_per(unsigned char, unsigned short, unsigned char);  
};
```

mainwindows.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ...
  //--- обьявление и запуск таймеров
    pB_timers[0] = new QTimer(this); pB_timers[1] = new QTimer(this);
    pB_timers[2] = new QTimer(this); pB_timers[3] = new QTimer(this);
    pB_timers[4] = new QTimer(this);
    // -- связываем конэктами
    connect(pB_timers[0],SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(DD1_timer_0()));
    connect(pB_timers[1],SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(DD2_timer_1()));
    connect(pB_timers[2],SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(DD3_timer_2()));
    connect(pB_timers[3],SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(DD4_timer_3()));
    connect(pB_timers[4],SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(DD5_timer_4()));
    // -- запускаем
    pB_timers[0]->start(1500); pB_timers[1]->start(1500);
    pB_timers[2]->start(1500); pB_timers[3]->start(1500);
    pB_timers[4]->start(1500);


    //--- создание отдельного потока для приёма сообщений
    // поток приёма данных
    QThread *thread = new QThread(); // инициализ класс потока
    MyThread_priem *mythread_priem = new MyThread_priem(); // инициализируем второй класс

    mythread_priem->Start_tehn_per(can_usb,speed_bit,can_device);

   connect(thread,SIGNAL(started()),mythread_priem,SLOT(Receiving_a_Message())); // дальше этого кода не идет "так мне qdebagi показали"  
    connect(mythread_priem,SIGNAL(update_m(ulong,unsigned char,unsigned char,QString,ulong,unsigned short,unsigned short)),this,
            SLOT(RepaintReceivedMessage(ulong,unsigned char,unsigned char,QString,ulong,unsigned short,unsigned short))); // соединение источника данных с приемником
    mythread_priem->moveToThread(thread); // отправляем в поток
    thread->start(); // цикл обработки сообщения в потоке
}
```

---

**Пояснение к коду** 
Запускается программа , запускаются таймеры и запускается дополнительный поток, дополнительный поток постоянно собирает информацию по сети и как только приходит сообщение он отправляет эти данные на от рисовку в основном потоке. А таймеры работают по принципу ждут и после определенного времени запускают слоты лежащие в основном потоке (объявленны они тоже в основном потоке).

Как можно увидеть они даже не  пересекаются, что я делаю не так??

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас объявлен массив из 4 элементов, а пытаетесь использовать 5 элемент:
pB_timers[4]. Ну как то так.

Comment: Забыл что массивы при объявлении не с нуля начинаются